# A chrome based browser addon to open link on a new/existing window on a different screen/monitor

Tags: chrome

While opening links in Brave/Chrome there are options to

- Open in new tab
- Open in new window

I would like an option to **open in new monitor or screen**. I want to open new links on the other screen.  This is so I can compare the original page and the newly opened page side by side.

Is there an addon that might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have settled on, uses the least number of keystrokes.

- I have another browser window open on the other monitor
- I grab the link from the current page and drag it to the tab area of this window.
- I can do multiple ones and each one opens a new tab on the other screen.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an add on which can do this but I have another suggestion.

If you are using Windows, you can simply move a new window by shortcut. For example to move a window to the right screen press: <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>➔</kbd>

So my workflow is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click link: opens new window in chrome. Now hands are already on keyboard and i press the shortcut to move the window.

If you are using a Mac, you may want to consider [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/). Rectangle describes itself like this:

> Move and resize windows in macOS using keyboard shortcuts or snap areas

Answer (score 1):

So if I got you right, you're looking for an addon that keeps an eye on any changes that happen on a new tab, right? Well, I actually use this cool one called [HARPA.AI](https://harpa.ai/), which comes with a guide on how to monitor pages https://harpa.ai/guide/monitor-price-drops in new tab. Hope that helps!

Comment: Not quite, the pages are normally different but related.